# "Merge" fields two structs of same type

Tags: go, struct

Looking at this `struct`:

```
type Config struct {
  path string
  id   string
  key  string
  addr string
  size uint64
}
```

Now I have a `DefaultConfig` intialized with some values and one loaded from a file, let's say `FileConfig`.
I want both structs to me merged, so that I get a `Config` with the content of both structs. `FileConfig` should override anything set in `DefaultConfig`, while `FileConfig` **may not have all fields set**.
(Why this? Because a potential user may not know the default value, so removing that entry would be equivalent to setting the default - I think)

I thought I'd need reflection for this:

```
 func merge(default *Config, file *Config) (*Config) {
  b := reflect.ValueOf(default).Elem()
  o := reflect.ValueOf(file).Elem()

  for i := 0; i < b.NumField(); i++ {
    defaultField := b.Field(i)
    fileField := o.Field(i)
    if defaultField.Interface() != reflect.Zero(fileField.Type()).Interface() {
     defaultField.Set(reflect.ValueOf(fileField.Interface()))
    }
  }

  return default
 }
```

Here I am not sure:

- If reflection is needed at all
- There may be easier ways to do this

Another issue I see here is that checking for zero values may be tricky: what if the overriding struct *intends* to override with a zero value? Luckily, I don't think it applies to my case - but this becomes a function, it may become a problem later

Comment: The only way to get around the zero values is not to have raw ints or strings in your config struct. Or at least not for values that are non-zero by default, but could be set to zero. You would have to use `*int` etc for those.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Foreword:** The [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package uses reflection (package [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)) to read/write values, including structs. Other libraries also using reflection (such as implementations of TOML and YAML) may operate in a similar (or even in the same way), and thus the principle presented here may apply to those libraries as well. You need to test it with the library you use.

For simplicity, the solution presented here uses the standard lib's `encoding/json`.

---

An elegant and "zero-effort" solution is to use the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package and **unmarshal into a value of the "prepared", default configuration**.

This handles everything you need:

- missing values in config file: default applies
- a value given in file overrides default config (whatever it was)
- explicit overrides to zero values in the file takes precedence (overwrites non-zero default config)

To demonstrate, we'll use this config struct:

```
type Config struct {
    S1 string
    S2 string
    S3 string
    S4 string
    S5 string
}
```

And the default configuration:

```
var defConfig = &Config{
    S1: "", // Zero value
    S2: "", // Zero value
    S3: "abc",
    S4: "def",
    S5: "ghi",
}
```

And let's say the file contains the following configuration:

```
const fileContent = `{"S2":"file-s2","S3":"","S5":"file-s5"}`
```

The file config overrides `S2`, `S3` and the `S5` fields.

Code to load the configuration:

```
conf := new(Config) // New config
*conf = *defConfig  // Initialize with defaults

err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(fileContent)).Decode(&conf)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%+v", conf)
```

And the output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cZf52lpOF-)):

```
&{S1: S2:file-s2 S3: S4:def S5:file-s5}
```

Analyzing the results:

- `S1` was zero in default, was missing from file, result is zero
- `S2` was zero in default, was given in file, result is the file value
- `S3` was given in config, was overriden to be zero in file, result is zero
- `S4` was given in config, was missing in file, result is the default value
- `S5` was given in config, was given in file, result is the file value

Comment: Supercool, but there's a little caveat for my case....the file MUST be in TOML syntax, and the function which reads it does already return it as `Config` instance....thus, everything will be overwritten by this `fileContent` instance...I didn't specifically mention this case so I might want to accept your answer

Comment: Turns out I can use the TOML Reader the exact same way as the JSON Reader...awesome!

Answer (score 7):

Reflection is going to make your code slow.

For this struct I would implement a straight `Merge()` method as:

```
type Config struct {
  path string
  id   string
  key  string
  addr string
  size uint64
}

func (c *Config) Merge(c2 Config) {
  if c.path == "" {
    c.path = c2.path
  }
  if c.id == "" {
    c.id = c2.id
  }
  if c.path == "" {
    c.path = c2.path
  }
  if c.addr == "" {
    c.addr = c2.addr
  }
  if c.size == 0 {
    c.size = c2.size
  }
}
```

It's almost same amount of code, fast and easy to understand.

You can cover this method with uni tests that uses reflection to make sure new fields did not get left behind.

That's the point of Go - you write more to get fast & easy to read code.

Also you may want to look into `go generate` that will generate the method for you from struct definition. Maybe there event something already implemented and available on GitHub? Here is an example of code that do something similar: https://github.com/matryer/moq

Also there are some packages on GitHub that I believe are doing what you want in runtime, for example: https://github.com/imdario/mergo

Comment: I like it; nevertheless need to think more about it as we may need this to be more generic....it's a complex project with different sections of config, so this type of solution may become very long...as for the slow part, it's on initialization only, so we may live with a bit of a slower but more generic solution

Comment: You make want to look into `go generate` that will generate the method for you from struct definition. I'll update my answer to add this point.

Answer (score 2):

> Another issue I see here is that checking for zero values may be
>   tricky: what if the overriding struct intends to override with a zero
>   value?

In case you cannot utilize `encoding/json` as pointed out by [icza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47396406/965900) or other format encoders that behave similarly you could use two separate types.

```
type Config struct {
    Path string
    Id   string
    Key  string
    Addr string
    Size uint64
}

type ConfigParams struct {
    Path *string
    Id   *string
    Key  *string
    Addr *string
    Size *uint64
}
```

Now with a function like this:

```
func merge(conf *Config, params *ConfigParams)
```

You could check for non-nil fields in `params` and dereference the pointer to set the value in the corresponding fields in `conf`. This allows you to unset fields in `conf` with non-nil zero value fields in `params`.

Comment: In my example I showed `encoding/json` handles properly when the file contains the zero value, and it will override the non-zero default value, and the result will be the zero value, as intended.

Comment: Yeah, I know @icza, your solution is great and I'd recommend it. What I meant to add with my answer is that *in case they **cannot** use your solution*, maybe because they aren't loading the config from a json file or something, they could approach it differently.

Answer (score 0):

This solution won't work for your specific question, but it might help someone who has a similar-but-different problem:

Instead of creating two separate structs to merge, you can have one "default" struct, and create a modifier function for it. So in your case:

```golang
type Config struct {
  path string
  id   string
  key  string
  addr string
  size uint64
}

var defcfg = Config {
  path: "/foo",
  id: "default",
  key: "key",
  addr: "1.2.3.4",
  size: 234,
}
```

And your modifier function:

```golang
func myCfg(c *Config) {
  c.key = "different key"
}
```

This works in tests where I want to test many small, different variations of a largely unmodified struct:

```
func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
  modifiers := []func (*Config){
    .... // modifier functions here
  }
  for _, f := range modifiers {
    tc := defcfg // copy
    f(&tc)
    // now you can use tc.
  }
}
```

Not useful when you read your modified config from a file into a struct, though. On the plus side: this also works with zero values.